# Ring (or Ideal) version of Boyen's signature

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

[Boyen's signature](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~xb/pkc10b/latticefull.pdf) is a well-known post quantum digital signature scheme. It's a lattice based scheme that uses a trapdoor of the lattice $\Lambda^{\perp}(A)$ and it's security is based in the SIVP problem. In section 2.3 of this paper [Ring Variant](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/014.pdf) it's commented how to construct a ring variant of this scheme to improve the efficience (by reducing the size of the public key).

The idea is really clear, but it's not formalized and the citations mentioned there are quite tricky (it is written there that they you can easily find an analogue version of 3 algorithms but in fact you can just find 1). Does someone know if this ring variant is defined somewhere? It is still a work to do? I want to use this scheme in my thesis but I cannot find a proper formalitzation of this scheme anywhere.

I would appreciate any information, citation, book... that you can provide.